Correct Location of Android & Ios Manifest
What is the correct location for Android manisfest and Ios in Flutter
Here is my code
I need the correct location details, so that this can work successfully
Future<void> _updateAndroidManifest(String appId) async {
    try {
      final manifestPath = File('/reward_ads_app/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml');
      if (await manifestPath.exists()) {
        String manifestContent = await manifestPath.readAsString();
        manifestContent = manifestContent.replaceAll(testAndroidAppId, appId);
        await manifestPath.writeAsString(manifestContent);
        print('AndroidManifest.xml updated successfully');

        // Log the updated content
        String updatedContent = await manifestPath.readAsString();
        print('Updated AndroidManifest.xml content:\n$updatedContent');
      } else {
        print('AndroidManifest.xml file not found at path: ${manifestPath.path}');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error updating AndroidManifest.xml: $e');
    }
  }

  Future<void> _updateInfoPlist(String appId) async {
    try {
      final plistPath = File('ios/Runner/Info.plist');
      if (await plistPath.exists()) {
        String plistContent = await plistPath.readAsString();
        plistContent = plistContent.replaceAll(testIosAppId, appId);
        await plistPath.writeAsString(plistContent);
        print('Info.plist updated successfully');

        // Log the updated content
        String updatedContent = await plistPath.readAsString();
        print('Updated Info.plist content:\n$updatedContent');
      } else {
        print('Info.plist file not found at path: ${plistPath.path}');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error updating Info.plist: $e');
    }
  }

I have written the above code but it is not workin
